# How to debug Task.Factory

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, task

If I have a given method, for example:

```
protected Task CreateItemsAsync(object source)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ///////
        code
        ///////
     }
}
```

I have a bunch of code in the method but I cannot step into the method. Is there a way to proceed step by step in the code?

Comment: What do you mean by "it just marks"? If you mean when you step through in the debugger, then that's because the statement is just *starting* the task. You should be able to add a break point on lines *within* the lambda expression.

Comment: It marks the whole area of code but does not stop on the breakpoints  which I have in the method when I step into.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you mean by "it marks". You shouldn't expect it to stop while you're stepping through, because `StartNew` *just* starts the task in the background. The debugger will stop on the breakpoints when you continue to run the program though.

Comment: Try putting the breakpoint in a code line *inside* the lambda expression.

Comment: I found out that when the await is called for the returned Task then I step into the code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code in a Console app:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        private static void Main()
        {
            var task = test();
            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }

        private static Task<int> test()
        {
            return Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                int x = 10;  // <-- Set a breakpoint here.
                int y = 5;
                int z = x/y;

                return z;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Set a breakpoint at the indicated line, and then debug the program.

The debugger will stop at the indicated line, and you will be able to single-step through the rest of the lines in the thread.

Comment: Doesn't work for function calls, for example:                     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ CppModuleRunner.InstantiateAndRunCppClass((CppIPModule)module, tokenSource.Token); });

Comment: @empty It does work - I just tried it. I put a single line, `Console.WriteLine("TEST");` in the lamda, set a breakpoint at that line and the debugger stopped at it. What version of Visual Studio are you using? (If this didn't work, people would be up in arms about it!)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. VS 2013.  C++/CLI. I'm doing remote debugging.

Comment: @empty Well, this question and answer relates to C#, not C++... It might well be different for C++.

Comment: This only works for anonymous inline functions such as is listed above.  It does not work in C# stepping into a named function such as Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>Foo.Bar());

Comment: @empty I never clamed otherwise. This question and answer is specific to anonymous inline functions (i.e. where you have `() => {...}` inside the `StartNew()`.

Comment: does not answer the actual question, rather a way around without mentioning the possibility; if what OP is asking can be done or not

Comment: @Manti_Core It does answer the OP's question, which was about debugging into an anonymous function. That's why the OP marked it as the answer....

Comment: yes may be OP changed the actual implementation to what you have suggested, but i have a similar case as OP queried but i cant change the implementation because in my case it is just fire and forget task and not wait for task to return something or make it sync by waiting for result. PS : i don't not want to await and execute in similar way mentioned in the question. If you can show how to step in to task that is not awaited it would be helpful.

Comment: @Manti_Core Is the source code for the method being run from the task available to you? Because if you set a breakpoint in the code, it should be hit and shown in the debugger when it is excecuted. It's just that WHEN it is hit is not predictable. (Incidentally, the OP has not changed the implementation - it always was an anonymous method.)

Comment: is there a way to control the debugger to hit the part inside task when we want(tried dragging the cursor in task forcefully din't work)? there must some way to debug task right instantaneously? otherwise no one would ever know the outcome. In my case the debugger is never there.